# How to determine the changed entity on a ISaveChangesInterceptor SavedChangesAsync on dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

When implementing ISaveChangesInterceptor. I need is to get a handle to the entity that was written to the database. So I can confirm it was a success, as I also would like to have database created values to the record as inserted.
for example here on code bellow it never is Added it is Unchanged.
While if I override the SavingChangesAsync it is Modified. But, the SavingChangesAsync occurs before writing into the database and SavedChanges is after. So the SavingChanges do not have db computed values as I think occurs before any error that may be encounter while saving.

```
public async ValueTask<int> SavedChangesAsync(SaveChangesCompletedEventData eventData, int result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
         eventData.Context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
         foreach (var entity in eventData.Context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
         {                
            if (entity.State == Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Added)
            {
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `var entities = eventData.Context.ChangeTracker        .Entries()        .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added)        .Select(x =>x.Entity)        .ToList();` ?

Comment: That's the same that is written there just a different syntax. the result is the same.
I will try to use the expression just to try it. should produce the same result.
If use this same code on SavingChangesAsync it does reflect the modified or added states. Seems like SavedChangesASync is called after the framework change the entity state to unmodified.

Comment: Confirmed it returns exactly the same. the entityState is Unchanged not added or modified as I would like it to be.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Did you find a solution or workaround?

Comment: I have not found any solution. Eventually I moved out of this because other business logic requirements.
As a work around I did stored a value that I used to determine if the value on SavedChanges was the same I was tracking and was able to get the database generated value. But I used for a limited period of time as other situations (not related to this issue) on the code force me to implement in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me:

```
    private readonly List<Action> _newEntities = new();


public override ValueTask<int> SavedChangesAsync(SaveChangesCompletedEventData eventData, int result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{

    foreach (var newEntity in _newEntities)
    {
        newEntity.Invoke();
    }
    _newEntities.Clear();


    return base.SavedChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
}

public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
    ...

    foreach (var entityEntry in dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditableEntity>())
    {
        ...
        
        if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {

            _newEntities.Add(() =>
            {
                var newId = entityEntry.Entity.Id;
                var propsWithValues = GetPropertiesWithValues(entityEntry);
                _dbLogger.Log(tableName, newId, felhasznaloId, now, string.Join(", ", propsWithValues), 1);
        
            });
        }
    }

    return base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Tóth Zoltán!! I was faced with the same issue and I tested your code and it actually does work.
Cheers!

Comment: Since the instance of an intercepter is re-used, this is not thread-safe! F.e. if thread A calls SaveChanges, but it fails, the added entities will still be added to that list. If meanwhile thread B does a successful SaveChanges, it will also log entities from thread A which don't even exist in the DB.